# How to import iOS native framework into Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to contribute in this [Flutter_blue plugin project](https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/tree/master/ios) adding the functionalities for native iOS using Objective C framework `CoreBluetooth`. How do I import the framework in to the library so I can start using its APIs?

**Update:**

`CoreBluetooth` is not suitable for `Flutter` project, because it's not a cocoapod dependency. So what I did what, go to cocopods website and look for other bluetooth dependencies from there. You can also find instructions of how to install a dependency there. For me, I made added `pod <depdencyname>` to `<plugin-project>/example/ios/Podfile` in the plugin project. Then added `dependency: <dependencyname>` to the  in `<plugin-project>/ios/pubspec`

Comment: Packages that access native API are called plugins. https://flutter.io/developing-packages/ provides an introduction how to develop them.

Comment: I have already have to project structure for the plugin. The problem here is that I try to use external Objective C framework `CoreBluetooth` but I have no idea how to add native ios dependency.

Comment: I don't know. I think to remember podfiles were mentioned for this.

Comment: Are you asking how to add a Cocoapod dependency to the Flutter plugin you're creating?

Comment: @RedBrogdon yes, and the framework is CoreBluetooth

Comment: thanks @RedBrogdon I think I know the problem now, and have updated my post

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem for a few time and found a solution by adding this lines to your podspec file at your iOS/ folder in your plugin dir:

```
  s.preserve_paths = 'yourframework.framework'
  s.xcconfig = { 'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '-framework yourframework' }
  s.vendored_frameworks = 'yourframework.framework'
```

Then, on your Flutter project, in the iOS folder, just run `pod update` on terminal so it can fetch the new dependencies.

You can find the full issue open by me with this problem [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17978).

Comment: I did as you said in your answer, but if I would like to write my plugin in swift and I try to use an Objective-c local library (not on CocoaPods) in it, Xcode (and the compiler later) complains about it by saying that the module that I try to import does not exist. There is a way to do it?

Comment: But where should I put the framework file? I tried `ios/`,`example/ios` but neither works.

Comment: @LorenzoImperatrice did you find a solution? thanks

Comment: @ÁlvaroAgüero No, in the end i decided to put it in the principal iOS project, In this way I had no problem at all. I found at the time that create and use the library as external plugin was surely more elegant, but was requiring too much time to understand how to setting up the podfile and plugin podspec for get everything works. The apple documentation about this kind of things is definitely not enough and bad..

Comment: @LorenzoImperatrice thanks, can you give some link or help to put it in the principal iOS project?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to add a CocoaPod dependency to the iOS "half" of a Flutter plugin, I believe the correct way to do so is to update the podspec file in the `/ios` folder of the plugin source. I recently did some work on the AdMob plugin, for example, and its podspec lists the SDKs for Firebase and Google Mobile Ads:

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/firebase_admob/ios/firebase_admob.podspec

And that's how they get included in the build.

Comment: do you build the code in Xcode after ios dependencies in podspec?

Comment: I didn't. `flutter run` should do that for you.